# include lua library in kreversi using cmake (kdegames)

Tags: lua, cmake, kde-plasma

So, i'm working on adding lua script into [kreversi](http://games.kde.org/game.php?game=kreversi). I am a newbie on cmake and this is my first time trying to code into kde projects.

I'm using lua5.2 and found out that cmake doesnt officially support lua5.2 library. So i searched and found [this cmake](https://github.com/beoran/eruta/blob/master/cmake/FindLua52.cmake) for lua5.2 and imitate his or her CMakeList.txt and modified accordingly to the kreversi CMakeList.txt.

here is my modified kreversi CMakeList :

```
project(kreversi)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

if(NOT COMPILING_KDEGAMES)
    find_package(KDE4 REQUIRED)
    include(KDE4Defaults)
    include(MacroLibrary)
    find_package(KDEGames 4.9.0 REQUIRED)

    add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS} ${KDE4_DEFINITIONS})
    add_definitions(-DQT_USE_FAST_CONCATENATION -DQT_USE_FAST_OPERATOR_PLUS)
    include_directories(${KDEGAMES_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${KDEGAMES_INCLUDE_DIR}/highscore ${KDE4_INCLUDES} ${QDBUS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif(NOT COMPILING_KDEGAMES)

add_subdirectory( pics ) 
add_subdirectory( sounds ) 
add_subdirectory( icons ) 
add_subdirectory( doc )

find_package(Lua52 REQUIRED) #### I ADDED THIS LINE #####

include_directories( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libkdegames/highscore ${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR} ) #### I MODIFIED THIS LINE #####

########### next target ###############

set(kreversi_SRCS 
    kreversichip.cpp
    kreversigame.cpp
    kreversiscene.cpp
    kreversiview.cpp
    Engine.cpp
    highscores.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    main.cpp )

kde4_add_kcfg_files(kreversi_SRCS preferences.kcfgc)

kde4_add_app_icon(kreversi_SRCS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/icons/hi*-app-kreversi.png")
kde4_add_executable(kreversi ${kreversi_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(kreversi ${KDE4_KDEUI_LIBS} kdegames ${LUA_LIBRARIES}) #### I MODIFIED THIS LINE #####
install(TARGETS kreversi  ${INSTALL_TARGETS_DEFAULT_ARGS} )

########### install files ###############

install( PROGRAMS kreversi.desktop  DESTINATION  ${XDG_APPS_INSTALL_DIR} )
#install( FILES kreversi.kcfg  DESTINATION  ${KCFG_INSTALL_DIR} )
install( FILES kreversiui.rc  DESTINATION  ${DATA_INSTALL_DIR}/kreversi )
```

When i try to run cmake, and then make, there are compile errors "undefined reference to `luaL_newstate()'" and "undefined reference to`luaL_openlibs(lua_State*)'" which may indicate something wrong with the linking process.

i tried :

```
message("lua library : " ${LUA_LIBRARIES})
```

and it outputs this :

```
lua library : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.so/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so
```

is that correct? how can i include and link lua5.2 in cmake?

I have already installed lua5.2-dev in my computer and without cmake, have successfully compile c-lua program with gcc test.c -I/usr/include/lua5.2 -llua5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind this. the error isnt from cmake but because i forgot to include lua.hpp and luaconf.h. it works in gcc before because i used it in pure c